# Typescript 1.6 abstract methods

Tags: angularjs, scope, typescript, typescript1.6, abstract-methods

I want to do this:

```
export abstract class Base{
    constructor(){
       this.activate();
    }

    protected abstract activate():void;
}

class MyClass extends Base{
    static $inject = ['myService'];
    constructor(service: myService){
        super();
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    activate():void{
        this.myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But I can't because type of 'this' in derived class method is of 'Base'. 
How can i make my code work?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: it is called, but then it throws: Cannot read property 'doSomethig' of undefined because in derived activate() 'this' is the 'base class' that has no 'myService' in it.

Comment: I should somehow tell it to look in MyClass for the MyService.doSomething, not in Base class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, the moment `activate()` gets called, `this.myService` is not yet set.

This is the callstack:

```
MyClass::constructor() -> super() -> Base::constructor() -> MyClass::activate()
```

So in the constructor of `MyClass`, you'll need to assign `this.myService` before calling the base constructor:

```
class MyClass extends Base{
    static $inject = ['myService'];
    constructor(service: myService){
        this.myService = myService; // <-- before super();
        super();
    }
    activate():void{
        this.myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I use this convention:
constructor(private service:myService)?